# How can I plot the solution obtained from my coupled ODEs?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have the differential equations

```
{[x]'[t] == -ι - (Δ1 - 1/(Δ2 - ι/2) - ι/2) ι x[t] + (ι y[t])/(Δ2 - ι/2),
 [y]'[t] == -2 ι + (ι x[t])/(Δ2 - ι/2) - (Δ1 -1/(Δ2 - ι/2) - ι/2) ι y[t]}
```

I solve them with

```
sol = DSolve[system, {x, y}, t]
```

How can I plot the solution obtained in the last line?

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

First correct the equations to x'[t]==... and y'[t]==....
Then I propose the following code:

```
    sol = DSolve[{x'[
                     t] == -ι - (Δ1 - 
    1/(Δ2 - ι/2) - ι/2) ι x[
   t] + (ι y[t])/(Δ2 - ι/2),
  y'[t] == -2 ι + (ι x[t])/(Δ2 - ι/
     2) - (Δ1 - 
    1/(Δ2 - ι/2) - ι/2) ι y[
   t]}, {x, y}, t]

    {xs[t_, Δ1_, Δ2_, ι_, a_, b_], 
  ys[t_, Δ1_, Δ2_, ι_, a_, 
     b_]} = {x[t], y[t]} /. First@sol /. {C[1] -> a, C[2] -> b}

   Plot[Evaluate[{xs[u], ys[u]} /. 
    u -> Sequence[t, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], {t, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

Comment: Dear sir, thanks a lot.

Comment: Dear Sir, not working for \[Iota]=\[Sqrt]{-1}. You have taken \[Iota]=1. Please check it.

Comment: @Aril - use `Sqrt[-1]` vice `[Sqrt]{-1}`

Comment: Dear Sir, Is it possible to plot without using absolute(Abs)?